# как определить эти три числа?

Tags: python, list, числа

> Дан список из 7 целых чисел, которые находятся в одной строке и разделены.
> Известно, что это три целых числа и все возможные суммы из данных трех чисел.
> Создайте приложение, которое по данному списку определит данные три числа.
>
> Пример:
> 2 2 11 4 9 7 9
> Результат:
> 2 2 7

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос.** Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и **укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи**. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу.

Answer (score 1):

```
"""
Дан список из 7 целых чисел, 
которые находятся в одной строке и разделены. 
Известно, что это три целых числа и все возможные суммы из данных трех чисел. 
Создайте приложение, которое по данному списку определит данные три числа.
"""
str_number = '2 2 11 4 9 7 9'
# Разделяем превращаем строку чисел в сортировоной сисок int 
number_list = sorted([int(x) for x in str_number.split()])
# Максимальный элемент массива для сравнения результата 
max_value = number_list[-1]
min_value = number_list[0]
# Добавляем минимальный элемент массива
result = [min_value]

# Начинаем перебор массива с 1 элемента
for i in range(1, len(number_list)):
    # Начинаем перебор массива со 2 элемента
    for j in range(2, len(number_list)):
        # Если минимальное число + i + j = максимальному добавляем i и j в список
        if (min_value + number_list[i] + number_list[j]) == max_value:
            result.append(number_list[i])
            result.append(number_list[j])

print(result)
```

Comment: Задача решается аналитически БЕЗ перебора.